# Javascript equivalent of jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How should i construct my code to get the effect of this jQuery

```
var divQuery = $('.html5gallery-thumbs-0').children();
    divQuery.on('click', function () {...}
```

I thought it is something like this :

```
 var divQuery = document.getELementsByClassName('html5gallery-thumbs-0');
        divQuery.onclick = function (elem) {
//this.style.display = 'none'
// OR
//elem.style.display = 'none'

}
```

Element should reference to the clicket object right? Or it should be the key word `this`. I want to learn `javascript` because `jQuery` is only library after all. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending kind users answer with two other approaches:

Using the latest and greatest JS features:

```
const divQuery = document.querySelector('.a');
divQuery.childNodes.forEach(v => {
  v.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.textContent);
   })
 });
```

And a really old one (which supports IE and other older browsers):

```
const divQuery = document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0];
  [].forEach.call(divQuery.children, function(v){
     v.addEventListener('click', function() {
     console.log(this.textContent);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just catch the parent with `querySelector` and get it's children with `children` function. Then - iterate over it and bind listener.

```js
const divQuery = document.querySelector('.a');

Array.from(divQuery.children).forEach(v => {
  return v.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.textContent);
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>child1</div>
  <div>child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that Array.from is quite new. You may also use Array.prototype.forEach.call

Comment: @Jonasw Nope, it's not **quite** new. ES6 is a standard, actually. I would rather say that using call on Array prototype functions is deprecated.

Comment: @Jonasw Feel free to make your own answer. That's my coding style which I recommend.

Comment: @Kinduser `Array.from` is not supported in IE; many projects still need IE support.

Comment: @RyanZim IE is not a browser, actually. Anyways you can just use old `for` loop instead of `forEach`, so `Array.from` won't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is almost correct. But when you are finding elements by class it gives you a collection of object. So, first select the index then assign the onclick function. Like below.

```
var divQuery = document.getELementsByClassName('html5gallery-thumbs-0');
        divQuery[0].onclick = function (elem) {
//this.style.display = 'none'
// OR
//elem.style.display = 'none'

}
```